# Conditionally remove rows based on another column in R

Tags: r, text, filter, statistics, economics

I have the following df:

```
city_code;  name;   job;
489         Jonh    Engineer 
489         Adam    Economist     
128         Mary    Entrepreneur  
128         Matt    Physician    
147         Rob     Entrepreneur
147         Gomez   Retired
199         Thomas  Entrepeneuer
199         Ryan    Entrepeneuer
```

My df has thousands of rows. It has two different names for each city. I want to select every city that has only one person as Entrepeneuer in the job column. The df should look like this:

```
city_code;  name;  job;
128         Mary   Entrepreneur
128         Matt   Physician
147         Rob    Entrepreneur
147         Gomez  Retired
```

There are other columns that I want to keep in the df.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Learn how to subset (filter) your data frame [https://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html], and then do that twice. 

First keep all rows where job=='Entrepreneur', save this as a separate df, then keep all the rows where city_code is in this last df.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using the `reprex` package next time and try to avoid *typos* in the reproducible data set.
Here is a possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~ city_code, ~ name, ~ job,
    489, "Jonh"  , "Engineer",
    489, "Adam"  , "Economist",
    128, "Mary"  , "Entrepreneur",
    128, "Matt"  , "Physician",
    147, "Rob"   , "Entrepreneur",
    147, "Gomez" , "Retired",
    199, "Thomas", "Entrepreneur",
    199, "Ryan"  , "Entrepreneur"
  )
df %>% 
  group_by(city_code) %>% 
  add_count(job) %>% 
  filter((job == "Entrepreneur" & n == 1) | job != "Entrepreneur")
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   city_code [3]
#>   city_code name  job              n
#>       <dbl> <chr> <chr>        <int>
#> 1       489 Jonh  Engineer         1
#> 2       489 Adam  Economist        1
#> 3       128 Mary  Entrepreneur     1
#> 4       128 Matt  Physician        1
#> 5       147 Rob   Entrepreneur     1
#> 6       147 Gomez Retired          1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(city_code) %>% 
   filter(sum(job == 'Entrepreneur') == 1) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  city_code name  job         
      <dbl> <chr> <chr>       
1       128 Mary  Entrepreneur
2       128 Matt  Physician   
3       147 Rob   Entrepreneur
4       147 Gomez Retired
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, .SD[sum(job == "Entrepreneur") == 1], city_code]
   city_code  name          job
1:       128  Mary Entrepreneur
2:       128  Matt    Physician
3:       147   Rob Entrepreneur
4:       147 Gomez      Retired
```